# Printer driver for Canon MX452

Tags: drivers, printing, 13.04, canon, pixma

Does anyone know how I can get my Canon Pixma MX452 running on Ubuntu 13.04, either via USB or 802.11? I tried to install in 13.04 via USB, but it used a generic text-only driver which didn't work at all. No scanner functionality either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at this --> http://www.justanswer.com/printers/7ofxw-purchased-canon-pixma-mx452-having-trouble-connected-thru.html

Comment: Search the web for "MX450 series IJ Printer Driver Ver. 3.90 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)"

Comment: user2088077 - Thanks, that got the printer successfully installed (the driver can be downloaded here: http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100515301.html). Now all I need is to get the scanner working.

Comment: I got a *-deb.tar.gz file the above link. How do I install this? I extracted the file and tried to run the install.sh, however it just exists without much messages.

Comment: Rejeev Divakaran - did you try to run it from the terminal? If not, open a terminal, navigate to where the install.sh file is, and run "sudo ./install". That should start the installation.

Answer (score 5):

I have managed to install both the printer and scanner drivers for my Canon MX452, you can grab them from here,

- Printer: http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100515301.html
- Scanner: http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100517701.html

In both cases, you will have to extract the tar balls, and run the install.sh script. To run the script you might have to make it executable by running:

```
$sudo chmod a+x install.sh
$./install.sh
```

The printer script will have menus for you to choose between find the printer via USB or Network. I installed mine via network, but in both cases you need to have the printer powered and ready.

I wasn't able to use my scanner using "Simple Scan" but the "scangearmp" application that is installed by the script works just fine. You can start it from terminal by running:

```
$scangearmp &
```